# How to draw a line between PointF in a list

Tags: c#, list, canvas, xamarin.android

I'm just starting out with xamarin for android. I'm building an app where a person can see the track they walked on a map. The map is handwritten with a bitmap (this is a requirement as it's a school assignment). I need to save points (which I did in a list) and draw dots and lines between the dots to create a track.

The problem is that I have a foreach method to draw all the dots, I just need to draw lines between the dots. I don't know how to make sure I have a registry of the previous points and the new points so I can put the coordinates in the drawLine method.

The track is a list which adds the current GPS location to the list. Since I use a bitmap for the map I needed to implement myself what coordinates of the map are corresponding with the coordinates of the real-life area. this is what the Proportion is referring to.

```
        paint.Color = Color.Magenta;
        PointF previousPoint;
        foreach (PointF p in track)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("works");
            // p is a track-point in RD-meters
            // calculates distance to centre bitmap
            float bpx = (p.X - centrePos.X) * 0.4f;
            float bpy = (centrePos.Y - p.Y) * 0.4f;
            // converter to screen pixels
            float sx = bpx * this.Proportion;
            float sy = bpy * this.Proportion;
            // calculate to absolute scherm-pixels
            float x = this.Width / 2 + sx;
            float y = this.Height / 2 + sy;
            canvas.DrawCircle(x, y, 10, paint);

            previousPoint = p;

            //draws the lines between the points
            canvas.DrawLine(previousPoint.X, previousPoint.Y, x, y, verf);
        }
```

so now previousPoint and p are the same, and it should be more like p1 and p2, but calculated to match the same centre as described in the code.

Comment: If you have a set of points, then just draw a line between point n and point n+1.

Comment: a) Hint: `foreach` is not always better than `for`. b) drawing multiple lines ought to be done with one `DrawLines` call.